# apksigner: command not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing, apksigner

**Specifications:**

- Android Studio Version: Android Bumblebee
- Android Build SDK Build-Tool : 30.0.3
- Android SDK Command-line Tools: 7.0

I am trying to sign apk using apksigner. I am using this command in my Android Studio Terminal

```
apksigner sign --ks release.jks app.apk
```

I am following the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) but I am getting this error

```
bash: apksigner: command not found
```

When I dig further I found that Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/7.0/bin does not have apksigner it has following command line tools

[image]

What am I missing here?
I tried downloading `cmdline-tools/6.0` and `3.0` but I don't see apksigner there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### You need to add a path variable in bash profile

**I have written this answer based on the discussion with Commansware and Pierre on Commansware answer.**

Let's discuss these questions to fix the **command not found** the issue on Android Studio.

> Where is apksigner?

You can find apksigner at `Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3`

> How to use apksigner using terminal?

1. with absolute path (painful way)

   $ ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/apksigner verify ~/Desktop/app-release.apk
2. with $path variable (the smart way)

   $ apksigner verify ~/Desktop/app-release.apk

For this, you need to set a path variable in your bash profile

> How to set path variable?

Add this to your bash profile

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3"
```

Now you should be able to run `$ apksigner verify ~/Desktop/app-release.apk` anywhere even inside Android Studio terminal.

> Still can't run the command on Android Studio?

In my case, I was not able to run `apksigner` command even after setting the path variable. So wrote `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3"` on Android Studio terminal. And it worked!

## Extra discussion

apksigner is part of [Android Studio CLI tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line). But I found that other Android Studio CLI tools (d8, avdmanager, aapt etc) command work by default except for apksigner. I don't know if it was just me or if it happens with others too.

Comment: Worked like a charm , thanks

Answer (score 2):

`apksigner` is part of the SDK build tools. So, you should find it in `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/30.0.3/`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have your Android SDK installed.

Comment: I did find it under $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/30.0.3/ but why apksigner gives command not found but other other command-line-tools work for eg:  sdkmanager , avdmanager works just fine

Comment: Is it possible to run apksigner command from Android Studio terminal ?

Comment: It is, but you need the build_tools/30.0.3 directory in your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Or, specify the fully-qualified path to the program when you run it. In other words, this works no differently than with any other program.

Comment: ....../Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/apksigner: line 31: dirname: command not found after setting export PATH="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/lib" @Pierre

Comment: @RohitSingh: I am unclear why you put `lib/` at the end of that. At least for me, on macOS and Linux, `apksigner` is directly in `30.0.3`.

Comment: I added an answer based on the discussion here with @CommonsWare and Pirre . Thanks